# Move the csv file(s) from the active folder to the sub-folder "archive"

Tags: vba, excel

The file is identified (GWB) but jams at the destination command. What am I missing?

```
Sub MoveCsvFiles()

Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim SFile As String              'source file
Dim GWB As String
Set Wkb = ThisWorkbook

    SFile = Wkb.Path & "\"
    GWB = Dir(SFile & "*.csv")
        Do While Len(GWB) > 1

            Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
            FSO.MoveFile Source:=Wkb.Path, Destination:=Wkb.Path & "\Archive\"

        GWB = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Found the problem. Source file not identified properly. Thanks all

```
FSO.MoveFile Source:=Wkb.Path & "\" & GWB, Destination:=Wkb.Path & "\Archive\"
```

Comment: Check the value of GWB or manually check the folder; I'm guessing that you're picking up multiple files

Comment: Use `Dir$` see if that works.

Comment: Found the issue. Correct string above. Thanks for looking